# How to change your firewall preferences when you cannot login to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, firewall, login, windows-firewall

Here is a toughie.

I just switched to a new computer at work and for some reason Firefox wasn't able to connect to the internet. So, I went into windows firewall settings in the control panel and accidentally enabled windows firewall for `Home or Work (private) networks`. (previously it was only enabled for Domain networks)

Then I restarted my computer. Now, because the firewall is enabled for `Home or Work (private) networks`, I cannot login because it tells me that the "logon servers are unavailable".

How would I go about disabling the firewall for `Home or Work (private) networks` when I can't  log into windows?

I was thinking I could get into the computer via safe mode, but that requires authentication as well. Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Firewall shouldn't cause this.  Are you currently hooked up to you work's network?

Comment: Yeah I'm cabled in. I have my old machine right next to it and if I switch the ethernet cable to the old machine it logs in fine.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the problem is unrelated to the firewall. Contact your IT department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the windows installation disk you can run the **Command Prompt** ([Recovery Console](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-7-recovery-environment-command-prompt/)), launch **Regedit** and after having loaded the registry hive, you can disable the firewall by changing the "EnableFirewall" value of  the following keys from **1** to **0**:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Defaults\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile
```

and

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Defaults\FirewallPolicy\PublicProfile
```